# Email template preview is not working on live Magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, email, email-templates

When i try to view the template in Live i am getting a blank screen but if try to view the template locally or on staging it works without any issues.

Can anyone give me a hint or any help idea to get this working

Comment: Not enough details. Which errors are getting logged into the console or logfiles?!

Answer (score 3):

Using the Kishan code gives me a screen that says "Email Preview" at the Top, with the Magento copyright info underneath but no template content in 2.3.4. I stumbled across this code on [git healthywebsites clintonwere](https://git.healthywebsites.co.uk:8888/clintonwere/test-project1/blob/80075511fa05cbbcc987f1139678d7f56b0c6eba/app/code/Magento/Email/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_email_template_preview.xml)  that gave me the result I expected. Hopefully it can help somebody else.

---

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="empty" />
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
            <block name="preview.page.content" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Email::template/preview.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Email\Block\Adminhtml\Template\Preview" name="content" as="content"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>`

Comment: Dear, can you please help me? I have the same problem in Magento 2.3.4. Can you tell where do I need to add this code? please give some instructions. The url of git.healthywebsites is not working.. Please help.

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_email_template_preview.xml

Answer (score 1):

In your Live site if that is in **Production mode**, then please try to create below file in your custom module here..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_email_template_preview.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
             <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then try to run all deployment command once and check.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Custom module for this layout file? and what is this xml file do?

Comment: You can add this in your backend theme or also in your any custom module's adminhtml layout. I think you're getting JS error, and this will fix your issue.

Comment: I mean why is the production mode breaking the JS my live is on production

Comment: Can you please check you console once ? There you're getting jQuery is not defined error. For that I have added above block in layout file. Try this and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I get error for 4 js files

- jquery.js    - ui.js   - modal.js   - translate.js

Comment: Yes, If you will add above XML file then you will not get this error again. Above code will include that JS file there and you can see preview of your email template.

Comment: thank you, I will check this now

Comment: Can i ask one thing to get the understanding, why is this working on local? i mean why is it working on developer mode

Comment: @jibingeorge, probably because in production mode some settings like js-minifying are set

Comment: working perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

The fix related to this issue is mentioned in this github issue on magento please have a look

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25068
> Commits
> https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e8eb43a84cb861cedda424aaf8be83aa1c6c1c29